# how do i create a database in psycopg2 and do i need to?

Tags: python, database, django, psycopg2

I'm create a blog using django.

I'm getting an 'operational error: FATAL: role "[database user]" does not exist.

But i have not created any database yet, all i have done is filled in the database details in setting.py.

Do i have to create a database using psycopg2? If so, how do i do it?

Is it:

python

> > > import psycopg2
> > >       psycopg2.connect("dbname=[name] user=[user]")

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

before connecting to database, you need to create database, add user,  setup access for user you selected. 
Reffer to installation/configuration guides for Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would create the database externally before trying to hook it up with Django.

Is this your private server?  If so, there are command-line tools you can use to set up a PostgreSQL user and create a database.

If it is a shared hosting situation, you would use CPanel or whatever utility your host provides to do this.  For example, when I had shared hosting, I was issued a database user and password by the hosting administrator.  Perhaps you were too.

Once you have this set up, there are places in your settings.py file to put your username and password credentials, and the name of the database.

Comment: i'm not sure if i have PostgreSQL installed, and how would i create the database. And yes, it is a private server.